# Ratio of value_counts for a binary target variable grouped by another column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I created a toy data set to try and figure out how df.groupby works.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3], "B": ['m','f','m','m','f','m','f','f','f','m','f','m'],
                  'target': [0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,0]})
```

My 'target' variable has just 2 levels, 0 and 1. I can get a count total of each for variable `'B'`, like this:

```
b = df.groupby('B').target.value_counts()
```

And the output looks like this:

```
    B  target
f  0         3
   1         3
m  0         4
   1         2
Name: target, dtype: int64
```

But `'B'` categorical. What I would like to do is, for each level of `'B'`, get the ratio

> (value_counts for target=1)/(value_counts for target=0)

For example,

- for B=f, I need 3/3
- for B=m, I need 2/4.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it using `.apply()`

```
def cal_ratio(x):
    n_1 = sum(x['target'].values == 1)
    n_0 = sum(x['target'].values == 0)
    return '{:}/{:}'.format(n_1, n_0)

b = df.groupby('B').apply(cal_ratio)
print(b)

# Output
# B
# f    3/3
# m    2/4
# dtype: object
```

Comment: That's what I needed. It was no big deal for me to change the output of the function to numeric. I forgot to mention I wanted to graph the results but I figured that bit out. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [pandas.Series.unstack](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
c=b.unstack()
c[1]/c[0]
```

Output:

```
    B
f   1.00
m   0.50
dtype: float64
b
```

Comment: That's short and sweet.